# I want to use preg_replace function to append a php code in other file just after the php tag start in other file

Tags: php

Here is code

```
$myFile = "process.php";
$gf = file($myFile);<br>
$data="include('connection.php');"; <br>
foreach($gf as $lineNumber => &$lineContent) { <br>
        if($lineNumber == 0) {<br>
                $lineContent .= $data;<br>
        }<br>
}

$content = implode("", $gf);<br>
file_put_contents($myFile, $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need include the new script on the first php tag ocurrency

```
$myFile  = "process.php";
$gf      = file($myFile);
$include = "<?php include('connection.php');" . PHP_EOL;


$content = preg_replace("/.*?<?php(?!\w)/", $include, file_get_contents($myFile), 1);

file_put_contents($myFile, $content);
```

Comment: no brother.. i want to use preg_replace function to do this work

Comment: Ok, I understand, check again